# Twilio POST request returns 401

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm getting a 401 when trying to POST a request to the Twilio REST API.
I've included the following header:

```
Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded '<accountSid>:<authToken>' string>
```

And I've also tried Basic Authorization without encoding the string but the result is the same.

Edit: This is the response body:

```
Not Authorized - only signed requests from Twilio are allowed. More info about this error at: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/why-does-my-twiml-bin-url-give-me-a-not-authorized-error-when-i-try-to-view-it
```

How do i sign a request? The docs aren't very clear about it.

Comment: Did you replace accountSid and authToken with actual values? What language/tool are you using?

Comment: What language are you use?

Comment: I'm using advanced REST client and I did replace accountSid and authToken with the values associated with my account.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist from Twilio and I'd love to help, but I can't without seeing a bit of what you tried to do. It looks like you're trying to make a POST request to a TwiMLbin (which you probably shouldn't be doing) so I'd love to see a bit more and help out.

Comment: Thanks philnash that was actually the problem, I was POSTing to a TwiMLbin. Changed that and it works!